# Submit form via ajax doesn't work on dropdown index change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is the wired situation. This is my form:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "myForm" }))
{
    <select name="statusId" onchange="this.form.submit();" class="selectField">
            <option value="-1">-- Pick Item --</option>
            <option value="1">Item XYZ</option>
    </select>
    <button>SUBMIT</button>
}
```

And I have this simple ajax call:

```
    $(".myForm").on("submit", function (event) {                
        event.preventDefault();                
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

When I click on button it works fine (use ajax).
But I don't need ajax on button I need it on select index change.
When I change selected index it make post to action method but not via ajax.
What I miss here?
What is the difference?

Comment: *When I change ajax* - what does this mean? What code have you tried to achieve your goal? The code you've posted is a form submit event handler so is not really relevant.

Comment: Sorry I write it wrong. I changes it. "When I change selected index". Yes it is event handler and it works with button click. But I need to make form post when I change index in dropdown.

Comment: @1110 I have provided a complete solution for you below, hoping I understood your requirements correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is all the code you need for all that to work:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $('.myForm')[0].submit();
    });
    $('select[name="statusId"]').on('change',function() {
        $('.myForm').triggerHandler( 'submit' );
    });
    $(".myForm").on("submit", function() {                                
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You do not need inline JS in the `select` element:

```
<select name="statusId" class="selectField">
```

Note: You may want to give the `button` a more specific selector if there are other buttons on the page.

Comment: I added button there just to explain that on button it worked but on dropdown change ittem it doesn't. It works now with solution you provided here. I just have multiple forms on a page but that is not problem right now :)

Comment: Great @1110!! Glad I could be of some assistance. Enjoy.